# Get filename in the middle of pipeline

Tags: powershell

I've got a perfectly fine regex but I want to add in the file in which the regex was found, current code:

```
$results = Get-ChildItem ../MyDir -filter "*.txt" -Recurse | Get-Content | 
             Select-String -pattern "Token: ([^']*)" -AllMatches | 
                 % {$_.Matches} | % {$_.Groups[1].Value}
```

Need:

```
$results = Get-ChildItem ../MyDir -filter "*.txt" -Recurse | Get-Content | 
             Select-String -pattern "Token: ([^']*)" -AllMatches |
                 % {$_.Matches} | % {<<FileNameMatchWasFoundIn>> + $_.Groups[1].Value}
```

Is this possible without breaking it into a big ole for loop?

Comment: Remove the `Get-Content` from the pipeline, Select-String will automatically read the file line by line when you pipe a FileInfo object to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe directly to `Select-String` and the resulting output objects will have a `Path` attribute with the file name:

```
$results = Get-ChildItem ../MyDir -filter "*.txt" -Recurse | Select-String -pattern "Token: ([^']*)" -AllMatches |ForEach-Object {
    New-Object psobject -Property @{
        File = $_.Path
        Matches = $_.Matches |% {$_.Groups[1].Value}
    }
}
```

If you just want a string as the result:

```
$results = Get-ChildItem ../MyDir -filter "*.txt" -Recurse | Select-String -pattern "Token: ([^']*)" -AllMatches |ForEach-Object {
    "{0}: {1}" -f $_.Path,$(($_.Matches|%{$_.Groups[1].Value}) -join ";")
}
```

Comment: Awesome, 99% of the way there - how do I get $results to contain File + Matches as a list of string?